SqlGeography Web Reference
Is there a way to pass a SqlGeography type (Microsoft.SqlServer.Types) as a web reference?
In our API project we use SqlGeography (Microsoft.SqlServer.Types), but when I use our C# client to access it as a web reference it generates code as follows, with is very much incomplete.
public partial class SqlGeography {

    private int sTSridField;

    public int STSrid { // e.g. 4326
        get {
            return this.sTSridField;
        }
        set {
            this.sTSridField = value;
        }
    }
}

